# How can UITapGestureRecognizer be aware of touch up and down?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a table view with rows of item. I also attach an `UITapGestureRecognizer` on it in order to make my controller to handle tapping a custom button in the item row. My question is, I want to apply detailed effects for touching down and touching up the button. I've tried to make use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` instead of `UITapGestureRecognizer` with `minimumPressDuration` set to 0.0f. It works, but it causes the table view failed to scroll. Please kindly help and thanks.

Comment: A tap gesture recognizer is not used to detect touch up and touch down. All it does is recognise a "tap" i.e. the user places their finger on the screen and then releases it within a certain amount of time without moving it. This will then fire a tap gesture recogniser. You'll need to use something different if you want to detect touch up and touch down.

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to attach a click listener to the button within the tablerow, I would suggest you to remove the UITapRecognizer, and add selectors to the button you need for each event.

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(touchedUp) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(touchedDown) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```